# Combining DateTime Column and smallint column in SQL into DateTime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column [DT] that is a datetime 'yyyy-mm-hh' format. The next column, [HOUR] is a smallint hour for the day. And it starts at 1 instead of 0. So 1 is midnight, 2 is 1 AM, etc.

I'm trying to combine these two into a datetime column. i.e., DT + [hour -1]. However, I was doing this in C#, and think it could be done in SQL. Here's what I have now:

```
SELECT  [DT]
    ,[HOUR]
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( YEAR(DT), MONTH(DT), DAY(DT), [HOUR] -1, 0, 0, 0 ) 
    FROM [Battery].[Forecast]
```

But it's complaining about using DT's year. I am pretty new to SQL, so any help would be great.

Comment: Ideally you should merge these together and put the result in a new column that is a datetime column. Storing date information across multiple columns that are not datetime is a problem that you will always be fighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, (2 - 1), '2016-01-22 22:22:22');
```

or in your case

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, ([HOUR] - 1), DT);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You welcome! You may want to accept this as the correct answer ;) and  also create a persistent calculated column in the table like that ALTER TABLE TheTable ADD
NewDate AS (DATEADD(HOUR, ([HOUR] - 1), DT)) PERSISTED

Comment: I will... I just have to wait a few minutes :D